# how to display file image of blob from wp_cf7dbplugin_submits table of contact form 7 db plugin

Tags: wordpress, fpdf

i have created form using contact form 7 plugin in wordpress and saved form inputs in database using contact form 7 db extension and on form submission a pdf file is generated using fpdf. But in That pdf i am not able to get image that is saved in BLOB type. so please help me in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is there code that you could post to help us answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
wp_get_attachment_thumb_file()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can you please explain me where to add this function.like this is my code

Comment: add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_application_form');
function save_application_form($cf7) {
 $title = $contact_form->title;
  $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
   if ( $submission ) {
 $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
 }
$fisrtname = $_POST["text-107"];
$lastname =$_POST["text-925"];
$image = $_POST["file-36"]
require(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/themes/Fameux/fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(50, 10,"$fisrtname $lastname", 0, 1, L);
$pdf->Image('$image',10,10,-300);
$pdf->Output(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/'.$fisrtname.'.pdf', 'F');
 }

Comment: if you want to get your image from post then use get_post_meta();